# PHP CSV dynamic table want to make all entries in fifth column links

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a dynamic table created from my PHP script. The information is sourced from a CSV file. I would like everything in the fifth column to be a link to another page. So that would be every array index/key 4 is a link. Unsure on how i would modify the code below to achieve this?

```
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
echo "<tr><td>First</td><td>Last</td><td>Email<td>Address</td
<td>File</td></tr>";
$f = fopen("filelog.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
   echo "<tr>";
   foreach ($line as $cell) {
     echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a counter and when you reach the 4th element, output a link.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($line as $cell) {
    if ($i == 4) {
        // Create the link.
        echo "<td><a href="..."> </a></td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: what if there are only 4 cells in a line?  you won't get a 5th column in your approach.

Comment: I guess it depends if "every array index/key 4" is in 0 based or 1 based context.

Comment: But your approach is *replacing* a cell's actual content with a link (if/else), not adding an extra column.

Comment: From the question, it is unclear if an extra column is required or not. The basic idea I was going off was, output something different at iteration N.

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter to your loop and look for every 5th iteration.

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
   echo "<tr>";
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($line as $cell) {
       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
       $i++;
       if($i % 5 === 0) {
         echo "<td>" . yourlinkstuff . "</td>";
       }
   }
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

I am using modulus because it's unclear from your question whether or not there are more than 4 "cells" per "line".  If the foreach($line as $cell) always iterates 4 times, you don't need a counter.  You could just tag on the 5th column after that loop, like so:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
   echo "<tr>";
   foreach ($line as $cell) {
       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
   }
   echo "<td>" . yourlinkstuff . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Also, unclear if every 4th/5th cell per line should be a link or if every 4th/5th cell across lines is a link.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input, I really appreciate it. I have a table that has five columns, "First, Last, Email, Address, File". Everything in the "File" column is a link to that file. So yes in the array starting at index 0 the "File" data will be at index 4. I didn't want an extra column. This is code that ended up doing the job, thank you!!

```
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
echo "<tr><td>First</td><td>Last</td><td>Email<td>Address</td>
<td>File</td></tr>";
$fp = fopen("filelog.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $i=1;
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        if(($i % 5) == 0) {
            echo "<td><a href=" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . ">" 
            .htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</a></td>";
        }
        else {
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        $i++;
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($fp);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```